# iCloud space not working

Tags: iphone, icloud

I have purchased iCloud space on my iPhone which currently have over 45GB storage left. I still get storage space warnings on the iPhone. I cannot download anymore apps, take photos or receive anymore WhatsApp messages due to lack of space. How to a fix this issue? thanks.
The previous answer to this question does not answer the question. It states the problem but not how to fix it.
Thanks

Comment: You can‘t fix it as such. The phone complains about low memory on the phone itself, the iCloud storage you bought is storage on Apple‘s servers. These are two different things. If you are low in memory on your phone, you need to remove unused apps or data.

Comment: You bought the iCloud space–now turn on iCloud features like iCloud Photo Library to allow stuff to be moved off your phone. It cannot solve every problem though.